# Using files with your ASP.Net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I am pretty new to ASP.Net and I am tying to access a couple JSON files in my directory. In my normal Visual Studio projects I could store these files in /bin/debug, where do i store these files here? I heard you have "App_Data" but i don't understand how i would configure this.

I tried:

```
string JsonString = File.ReadAllText("~/App_Data/" + filename); (stored file under self created App_Data map in Project/Project/)
string JsonString = File.ReadAllText(filename);
```

error:
[image]
(I do realise it says where i should store it but isn't there a better way to store these files in my project directoy?)

Comment: `App_Data` is just a folder, there's no need to "configure" it. However, you do need to use `MapPath` to convert `~/App_Data` to a real physical path.

Comment: I normally embed the files as resources - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file and https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/319292/how-to-embed-and-access-resources-by-using-visual-c

Comment: var path = string.Concat(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~\bin\"), filename);
         var json = File.ReadAllText(path);

Comment: @phooey The downside of that is that it makes the resource fixed which is not useful if you need to edit the file.

Comment: @LeszekRepie What is the "HostingEnvironment"?

Comment: I had to put a reference to System.Web.Hosting, thnx for the info people.

Answer (score 1):

In .Net Core I'm using the `IHostingEnvironment` to get the Root Path of my Application. Then you can do somethink like `Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "myfolder", filename)` to get the path of the file. Then you can use `File.ReadAllText` with that path.

To get the `IHostingEnvironment` you have to add it as an Parameter in the constructor:

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

public MyController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
}
```

Comment: This is for .Net Core isn't it?

Comment: Oh. Right. Sorry. I'm forgetting all the time, that .Net and .Net Core are not as compatible as I thought :D